# How to remove a constraint on table using entity framework db migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to alter the type of a table column from `int` to `long`.

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Files", "Size", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
```

It's throwing an error on migration:

```
The object 'DF__Files__Size__1FCDBCEB' is dependent on column 'Size'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Size failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

How do I remove the constraint in entity framework... do the migration, then put it back in?

Comment: You cannot alter column to Non nullable value. Thing is now the program must drop the table to create it with the new column settings while not loosing the data already in the table. If your just working with test data and don't care about it you could try  something like public      Configuration()
    {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

Comment: thanks mate, very helpful. Thankfully it was test data, I deleted all my tables, removed the original assignment of int, to long.. and removed the change from the latest migration.